# How can I generate/declare annotation field inside of Annotation?

Tags: java, sun-codemodel, jcodemodel

I want to get something like this:

```
public @interface Unfinished {
  String value();
   String value() default "someVal";
}
```

The problem is I cannot use JFieldVar because it looks like this:

```
String value; //no parentheses 
String value = "someVal"; //no parentheses, no "default", "=" sign
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way is to use jDefinedClass.direct:

```
annotationClass.direct("String value();")
annotationClass.direct("String value() default \"someVal\";")
```

But I don't like this approach. I'd to use something similar to JFielVar.